# How to upload folder structure to minio (ObjectStorage)

Tags: filesystems, nfs, object-storage, minio

It seems I can upload a file to minio (Web app), but a folder. An alert popped up every time as  `Error occurred uploading 'folder_name'`. Is this forbidden action? If I want to do that, how can I work around?

Thanks